# How to determine intersect objects in json array with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, object

I have json data like this:

```
[{
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Test 1",
        "Time": {
            "start": "22:00",
            "end": "22:30",
            "duration": 30
        }
    }, {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "Test 2",
        "Time": {
            "start": "22:05",
            "end": "22:35",
            "duration": 30
        }
    }, {
        "Id": 3,
        "Name": "Test 3",
        "Time": {
            "start": "23:25",
            "end": "23:40",
            "duration": 15
        }
    },{
        "Id": 4,
        "Name": "Test 4",
        "Time": {
            "start": "22:15",
            "end": "22:50",
            "duration": 15
        }
    }
]
```

And i want get result like this, determine which intersect by **Time**:

```
  [
    ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 4"],
    ["Test 3"]
]
```

I have solution, but it's too complicated and i use 4 loops inside each other

If there is an easier solution, please suggest, thanks!

Comment: Take a look at lodash's groupBy function.

Btw Why did 1,2,4 items got into the same "bucket", and item 3 into another?

Comment: this is for display in the interface, which cross in time

Comment: do want this in mongodb query or in javascript?

Comment: does't matter, i store data in mongodb, but for client use javascript

Answer (score 2):

Try aggregation, I am not sure this will work exact as per your requirement,

- `$addFields` add new field `startHour`, that splits string hour and minute from string, using `$split`, and `$arrayElemAt` return first element means hour
- `$group` by `startHour` and make array of `Name`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      startHour: {
        $arrayElemAt: [{ $split: ["$Time.start", ":"] }, 0]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$startHour",
      Name: { $push: "$Name" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lC0ylMO02U0)

Result:

```
[
  {
    "Name": ["Test 1","Test 2","Test 4"],
    "_id": "22"
  },
  {
    "Name": ["Test 3"],
    "_id": "23"
  }
]
```

Comment: i need watch start date(hour and minute) and end date(hour and minute), if it is possible determine cross time like described above?